# Does Kubernetes supports downloading of resources like mesosphere

Tags: kubernetes, mesosphere

We know that **mesosphere** provides mesosphere fetcher in DCOS to download resources into the sandbox directory. Does **Kubernetes** provides anything similar to same?

Comment: You might want to describe what mesophere fetcher does and what the sandbox directory is.

Comment: @JonahB Mesosphere fetcher http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/fetcher/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Kubernetes does not have any built-in feature to download and inject files into a container the way Mesos does.

The Mesos fetcher feature existed before Docker image support, in fact. Prior to images, the fetcher was the primary way to download the executable and any supporting files. Kubernetes never needed that feature because it requires a container image. That said, having both be optional can be useful.

The Mesos fetcher is supported by Mesos, Marathon, and Mesosphere DC/OS.

Kubernetes could hypothetically add support for arbitrary file fetching in the future, but there hasn’t been a lot of demand, and it would probably require either container dependencies within a pod (to use a controller-injected sidecar), a kubelet plugin (to download before container start), or a native fetcher-like feature.

Answer (score 1):

While Kubernetes does not have a feature like [Mesosphere Fetcher](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/fetcher/), it is still possible to copy / download resources into a Docker container using the following ways:

- Docker's [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) and [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) copy resources from the host into the container.
- Docker's `ADD` supports [tar extraction and remote URLs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) too.
- Download / extract resources inside the container using commands like:

  - `wget`
  - `curl`
  - `lynx`
  - `tar`
  - `gunzip`

Comment: Yes, you can download the file into the container at build time or write your own custom entrypoint script to download it at deploy time, but the Mesos fetcher allows you to do it at deploy time without modifying the image at build time. This allows you to inject configuration or large data files without requiring it to be present in the image repository.